# Get Instagram tagged user photos

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

How to get all Instagram tagged user photos? For example, I have user "user123", and someone tagged me. How to get all images with `@user123`?

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/@user123/media/recent?access_token=%%%&count=9` not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no API to get all photos which has a user tagged.

You can get all tagged users for a photo via API, but not all photos of a tagged user.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is:

```
GET https://www.instagram.com/user123/tags
```

for further reading the Instagram documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/mentions